# iOS texture allocation shows twice as much memory usage in profiler

Tags: ios, memory, cocos2d-iphone, profiling, textures

I  have been struggling with this one for whole morning. not being able to test on devices yet, i rely on what profiler shows only to roughly see there are no major issues. One of which I consider as serious is the fact that whenever I create 2D texture either in Cocos2d or in custom code - directly supplying openGL, I have in profiler all my textures are displayed as two allocations.

E.g. when I create a texture 512x512x4 which is roughly 1MB of data, my live bytes usage jumps by 2MB and I can see in list of live objects two heavy blocks of memory 1Mb each - exactly as my texture.

And let me stress that point - this is NOT a raw image file I supplied to the glTexImage2D(), which gets deleted in the destructor and I have checked it many times. Also the problem I observed also in Cocos2d example projects - simple all the memory for textures is doubled.

below two screeshots - one from cocos2d app , shows two textures 600KB each displayed in the profiler as FOUR allocated objects :
[image]

and custom allocated and created texture directly with openGL and image supplied via libpng - displayed as live two objects 1Mb each.
[image]

I would appreciate if anyone could enlighten me on this one. Perhaps in the device situation looks different.

Regards,
s.

Comment: I'm having the exact same pb. Did you find why this double-alloc and how to avoid/free it ?

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior in cocos2d. It first loads the image file as a UIImage, then converts it to a CCTexture2D. That means in most cases the memory usage is double of what you might expect. The next frame the additional memory ought to be released.

You can find more info about this behavior in my [memory optimization blog post](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/11/optimize-memory-usage-bundle-size-cocos2d-app/). You'll also learn that using .pvr.ccz will not only reduce this memory overhead significantly, they'll also load a lot faster than PNG (not to speak of JPG which are dreadfully slow to load in cocos2d).

Comment: I said this is NOT the image file memory. It is being duplicated when texture got created and stays ALIVE the whole time app runs - even though the image files are being released long time ago. Besides argument about cocos2d can't stand the chance as second screenshot shows clearly in my custom drawing prototype that texture memory is being duplicated the WHOLE time - not only when I load it - and it has nothing to do with the cocos2d, as I have said - I load image myself with pnglib, create texture with glTexImage2D and then release the file and temporary buffer.

Comment: EVERY texture I load seems to be doubled in the simulator - and my suspicion is that perhaps this is normal behavior for simulator - hence my question if someone could actually check this on the device.